# Javascript auto refresh div in table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `table` with a `div` inside of it that auto loads every 10 seconds to add or remove rows. The issue I'm having is that it's not putting it in the table. It's putting the rows above the entire table.

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_pilots').load('pilots.html').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div id="load_pilots">
      <?php $mining->activePilots(); ?>
</div>
```

the outcome of activePilots() is

```
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
```

What I want to happen is the table rows go into the table, but instead they are going above the table and my browser has them as "stray tags."

EDIT:
Some rows are static in the table, not adding the id to the table would not work because some rows stay there.

Comment: a `table` having a `div` as its child is no valid html. use a `tbody` element instead.

Comment: I need to keep the static rows there though. So using tbody would delete the static rows on the next load.

Comment: you could use 2 `tbody` elements one for the static content one for the dynamic

Comment: That works @RolandStarke if you make an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give id to your table and not div for that .

Comment: The table also has static rows in it as well. not all rows are updated. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Why dont you use append method of jquery ,if u dont want to completely refresh the table and only update it?

Comment: Because I need to replace it entirely. I may have the wrong idea of append though. If I use append wouldn't it just keep adding whatever is in the html file?